# how to configure high availibility with hadoop 1.0 on AWS ec virtual machines

Tags: linux, hadoop, high-availability

I Have already configured this setup using heartbeat and virtual IP mechanism on the Non VM setup.

I am using hadoop 1.0.3 and using shared directory for the Namenode metadata sharing. Problem is that on the amazon cloud there is nothing like virtual Ip to get the High Availibility using Linux-ha.

Has anyone been able to achieve this. Kindly let me the know the steps required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I am using the Hbase replication WAL on hbase. Hbase later than 0.92 supports this.

For the hadoop clustering on cloud , I will wait for the 2.0 release getting stable.

Used the following

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/replication/package-summary.html#requirements

On the client Side I added the logic to have 2 master servers , used alternatively to reconnect in case of network disruption.

This thing worked for a simple 2 machines backking up each other , not recommended for higher number of server.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's 2 parts to Hadoop to make it highly available. The first and more important is, of course, the NameNode. There's a secondary/checkpoint NameNode that can you startup and configure. This will help keep HDFS up and running in the event that your primary NameNode goes down. Next is the JobTracker, which runs all the jobs. To the best of my (outdated by 10 months) knowledge, there is no backup to the JobTracker that you can configured, so it's up to you to monitor and start up a new one with the correct configuration in the event that it goes down.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that part. Never tried to configure it on anything other than plain old linux/freebsd machines before. Is there a reason you need linux-ha for Hadoop? It's designed to run on plain old commodity servers without a need for other fancy HA setups. At least at the server/OS level.

Comment: Well I am using hbase on top of hadoop , and need high availability for the setup. It is just being deployed on the VMS for a demonstration.

Comment: What part of Hadoop/Hbase doesn't give you the high availability that you need that linux-ha solves for you? Shouldn't you try and use the built-in HA parts? Hadoop is lacking in some ways for certain parts for HA. I'm curious, what would linux-ha give you that is currently lacking in Hadoop/Hbase?

Comment: Well Hbase doesnt have a SPOF but namenode in hadoop is SPOF. so only need to get the Namenode running as HA service.

Comment: As mentioned, in the newer Hadoop there is a secondary/checkpoint NN which provides a backup. I don't know that you can have 2 'primary' NN instances running, they'd need to notify each other of the changes they are each making and resolve conflicts. That's why the secondary NN is setup as a hot spare. With the shared folder, it can just catch up from where the primary NN left off if it needs to.

Comment: See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/hdfs_user_guide.html#Checkpoint+Node for info on the Checkpoint Node or Backup Node.

Comment: New Hadoop is still in alpha so is out of question here. For the secondary Namenode it is not for backup, its name is confusing this has been mentioned on their website also. I have no problem setting it up on commodity hardware with actual network cards. The only problem I have is with Amazon Cloud VMs. There is a solution I guess which is related to Elastic Ips but that doesnt seem to fit my need here.

Comment: You said you were using 1.0.3...I linked you 1.0.3 docs, which gives you the newer Checkpoint/Backup nodes. Granted, I might have not seen something elsewhere which says those features are not working or are in alpha for 1.0.3. RE: The Amazon Cloud VMs...I dunno, I've never used them. Sorry, can't help you on those.